# defining friend function within templated class

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I use three different files to define a templated class. The class declaration is in a `.h` file, the implementation in a `.cpp` file and explicit instantiations are included in a `.inc` file.
I'm trying to define a friend function that it's able to access private data members of a templated class. 
As in the case of templated classes, the function will be defined, implemented, and instantiated in 3 separate files.
When I try the call the function, I get the following error messages:

`myclass.h:error: ‘doSomething’ is neither function nor member function; cannot be declared friend`

`myclass.h:error: expected ‘;’ before ‘<’ token`

`mymethod.h: error: ‘friend’ used outside of class`

Does anybody has any suggestion on how to solve this issue? I tried to simplify the code below.

#### myclass.h

```
  template<class T>
  class MyClass{

      friend T doSomething<T>( MyClass<T> *, T, int);
      friend  MyClass<T> * doSomethingElse<T>( const MyClass<T> *, const MyClass<T> *);
      public:
               ...
      private:
         T *m_pMyMatrix;
  };
```

#### mymethod.h

```
#include <myclass.h>
template <class T> friend T doSomething( MyClass<T> *, T, int);
template <class T> MyClass<T>* doSomethingElse(const MyClass<T>*, const MyClass<T>*);
```

#### mymethod.cpp

```
#include <mymethod.h>
template <class T>
T doSomething( MyClass<T> * pData, T val, int index){
   // the actual code does sth. more complex than the code below.
   pData->m_pMyMatrix[index]+=val;
   return pData->m_pMyMatrix[index];
}

template <class T>
MyClass<T>* doSomethingElse(const MyClass<T> * pData1, const MyClass<T> * pData2){
   ...
   T res1 = doSomething(pData1, val1, index1);
   ...
}
#include "mymethod-impl.inc"
```

#### mymethod-impl.inc

```
template float doSomething( MyClass<float> *, float, int);
template double doSomething( MyClass<double> *, double, int);

template MyClass<float>* doSomethingElse(const MyClass<float>*, const MyClass<float>*);
template MyClass<double>* doSomethingElse(const MyClass<double>*, const MyClass<double> *);
```

Comment: using friend function can be dangerous ! Anyone can write a static function with the same signature and gain control of your class ,unless your friend function is declared with a namespace.

Comment: @Edwin: I guess this falls under the old "prevent that Murphy guy from gaining control, opposing Macchiavelli is futile anyway".

Comment: @sbi: i am just stating when you use friend functions (you dedicate a known trusted entity) ,make sure that your friend is really the one you intended. Guess whatever you want.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should worK

```
template<class T>
class MyClass;

template <class T>
T doSomething( const MyClass<T> *, T, int);

template<class T>
class MyClass {
  friend T doSomething<T>( const MyClass<T> *, T, int);
public:
  ...
private:
  T *m_pMyMatrix;
};
```

That is, you need to declare the template before you can make it (or an instance thereof) a friend.

Comment: @Javier: try now, I have corrected the code (`friend` keyword should not be used in the template function declaration).

Comment: @David: Thanks. I had copied the declaration without looking at it closely.

Comment: @Javier: You won't get around _declaring_ the function template before you declare it a `friend` (and you will have to declare the class template in order to be able to declare the function template). However, you can _define_ that template later. All the compiler needs for the `friend` is the _declaration_ of function template (and all the compiler needs for that is the _declaration_ of the class template).

Comment: What sould I do in the case my `doSomething` friend function has now a new parameter of type `Foo<S>`? Should I define `doSomething<S,T>` as friend in both class definitions (for the `MyClass` & `Foo` classes)?

Comment: @Javier: I see that Simone is already helping you with this. So far, I fully agree with everything he wrote, which would make it pointless if I repeated it.

Answer (score 2):

I think I solved this:

***mymethod.h***

```
template<class T> class MyClass;

template<class T> 
T doSomething<T>(const MyClass<T>* pData, T val, int index);
```

***myclass.h***

```
#include "mymethod.h"

template<class T>
class MyClass {
    friend T doSomething<T>(const MyClass<T>* pData, T val, int index);

public:
    // ...

private:
    T *m_pMyMatrix;
};
```

***mymethod.cpp***

```
#include "myclass.h"

template<class T>
T doSomething(const MyClass<T>* pData, T val, int index)
{
    pData->m_pMyMatrix[index]+=val;
    return pData->m_pMyMatrix[index];
}

template<> float doSomething( const MyClass<float> *, float, int);
template<> double doSomething( const MyClass<double> *, double, int);
```

In practice, only thing you need is to declare the template function **before** MyClass definition.

Comment: You need to include **mymethod.h** in **myclass.h** before class definition (and remove *friend* declaration outside class MyClass' definition).

Comment: @Javier: You don't need to have the function definition, but only the declaration. Basically before you define `MyClass` you have to forward declare the `MyClass` template, and then declare the `doSomething` template function. The actual implementation can be placed anywhere.  In general life is much easier if templates are provided in a single header file, but there are reasons not to do so in some cases (compilation times, fixing the types that can be used as instantiations for the template --i.e. failing to instantiate the template with some other types...)

Comment: I don't think you can befriend an undeclared function template.

Comment: Compiles in g++ 3.4.5. Also, it's an undefined function, not undeclared.

Comment: Damn, I forgot to type one line!! Try now.. I added `doSomething` to mymethod.h

Comment: @Simone: GCC 3.4.5? That's probably half a decade old! Do you mean 4.4.5.? And Comeau disagrees.

Comment: I wrote 3.4.5.. and I inserted a line that was missing, see the edit

Comment: @Simone: Yeah, 3.4.5, that's the one I'm referring to. According to http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.4/, it's from November 2005. Pretty exactly half a decade old. For C++, this is half an eon.

Comment: As a side note, I would merge the two header files into a single header. The templated class and the template function are *so* coupled that it does not make sense to keep them separate.

Comment: @Simone: No need to down-vote your answer. AFAICT it's correct. What platform are you on that you can't switch to a recent GCC version?

Comment: It's strange, because at least it should be `float doSomething<float>(const MyClass<float> *, float, int)` and not `float doSomething<float>(MyClass<float> const*, float, int)`, see the position of `const`.

Comment: @sbi a self-inflicted punishment for the mess I did :). 
@Javier define it :) I see from your answer that, in fact, it's undefined. I thought you were doing it for disallowing float and double templates.

Comment: @Javier: Those two const are interchangeable.

Comment: @Simone, sorry, I didn't get your suggestion. could you please let me know what do you refer with 'define it'? It is already defined in `mymethod.h`, isn't it? I'm considering already the line you added.

Comment: @Javier no, this is only a declaration. Definitions should be in mymethod.cpp or in a file that mymethod.cpp directly includes (this is important!).

Comment: ok, now I learn also sth. new, `template<>` is then used to disallow specific data types? Because, when I consider: `template<> float doSomething( const MyClass<float> *, float, int);`, the error message is shown, when I use: `template float doSomething( const MyClass<float> *, float, int);` the error message dissapears

Comment: I have difficulty following your code inside a comment. To my knowledge, the second version shouldn't even compile. template<> is used to provide a specialization for a given type and if you don't define it, you get a linker error when you use it in your code (thus disallowing it).

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. Just, an additional doubt, can we call friend functions, inside of other friend functions? for example is `doSomething()` would call inside `doSomethingElse()` in my updated post. It seems to be that something's wrong with my explicit instantiations.

Comment: yes, you can. Anyway, only friend functions will be able to access MyClass' private members.

Comment: @Simone: What sould I do in the case my `doSomething` friend function has now a new parameter of type `Foo<S>`? Should I define `doSomething<S,T>` as friend in both class definitions (for the `MyClass` & `Foo` classes)?

Comment: The function should be friend only of types you are accessing private parts of. So, if I have understood correctly, it should be `MyClass` friend only as before.

Comment: @Simone: thanks for the clarifications. I didn't know that it was possible to have a shared friend function. In my case, the `doSomething` template function is accessing private members of both `MyClass` and `Foo` classes. How does the code would look like in this case?

Comment: @Simone, thanks! Could you please have a look at my response to your code (in the codepad website)?.

Comment: @Simone, now it's working, thanks! http://codepad.org/FISyfnVS. BTW, somebody mentioned that using `friend` functions could be dangerous due to illegal access to classes. Do you see any black hole in the code?